# Installing NuGet Package Requesting the Wrong URL

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget-package

I'm trying to install NuGet Packages in my .net core project but it's requesting the wrong address :

```
 GET http://nuget.aerdata.loc/nuget/AerData/FindPackagesById()?id='RabbitMQ.Client%5C'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
```

The error log:

```
info :   GET http://nuget.aerdata.loc/nuget/AerData/FindPackagesById()?id='RabbitMQ.Client%5C'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
error: Failed to retrieve information about 'RabbitMQ.Client\' from remote source 'http://nuget.aerdata.loc/nuget/AerData/FindPackagesById()?id='RabbitMQ.Client%5C'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
error:   No such host is known
```

I think the problem in the project.assets.json file :

```
   "sources": {
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\NuGetPackages\\": {},
        "http://nuget.aerdata.loc/nuget/AerData/": {},
        "https://aerdata.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Shared/nuget/v3/index.json": {},
        "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json": {}
      },
```

It should request the `"https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"` but i can't remove the other wrong urls:

```
"http://nuget.aerdata.loc/nuget/AerData/": {},
        "https://aerdata.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/Shared/nuget/v3/index.json": {},
```

How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just keeping checked nuget.org source in Visual Studio Tools->Options->Nuget Package Manager->Package Sources.

Then, retry.

Comment: I'm using VS CODE, should i install Visual Studio?